# Using CTE Result with IN in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression, sql-in

I am trying to find employees names with title who don't receive any bonus and I get the following error:

```
WITH Result AS
(
    SELECT
        A.assoc_id  
    FROM
        Employee A 
    WHERE 
        assoc_id NOT IN (SELECT B.assoc_ref_id FROM bonus B) 
)
SELECT
    E.firstname, E.lastname, T.assoc_title 
FROM
    Employee E 
INNER JOIN
    Title T ON E.assoc_id = T.assoc_ref_id
WHERE
    E.assoc_id IN (Result ) /*(Result ) throws error*/
```

However, this works fine for me and I get the desired result:

```
WITH Result AS
(
    SELECT
        E.firstname, E.lastname, T.assoc_title 
    FROM
        Employee E 
    INNER JOIN
        Title T ON E.assoc_id = T.assoc_ref_id
    WHERE
        E.assoc_id IN (SELECT A.assoc_id FROM Employee A 
                       WHERE assoc_id NOT IN (SELECT B.assoc_ref_id 
                                              FROM bonus B))
)
SELECT * FROM Result
```

What wrong am I doing in the first query? Can we use joins while querying CTE result at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Please refrain from images, instead paste the formatted text - or at the very least, embed your images rather than links.

Comment: @gmiley I have removed the link to images and provided the text query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fundamentally not understanding how to use a table expression.

You need:

```
where E.assoc_id in (select assoc_id from Result);
```

A bit more explanation - A CTE, just like a *sub-query* or *view*, produces a logical *table expression*; and, just like any other table, you can't just reference it since that does not make any sense to the optimizer, just like any other table you *query* it by *select*ing from it. In addition, in many cases the optimizer can and will *expand* the table expression to be logically part of the main query (ie not a distinctly executed and self-contained object).

Comment: You could also use a `JOIN` instead of an `IN`. Basically the CTE presents you with an in-memory table.

Comment: The question is not how to rewrite or improve the query, it's specifically why the predicate in the OP's question is not working as written.

Comment: I agree, and up-voted your answer, I just felt that a little more exposition on what a CTE is would help in their understanding of the **why** it wasn't working for them.

Comment: @gmiley Agree I have added some additional explanation.

Comment: @gmiley - "an in-memory table" would not be an accurate exposition or give the correct mental image.  If you do `WITH CTE AS (SELECT * FROM HugeTable) SELECT * FROM CTE 
 WHERE Id=1` it doesn't have to create an "in memory" table with the contents of HugeTable

Comment: @MartinSmith well, yes it does. It doesn't have to re-do it every time it is accessed, but a CTE is a "snap-shot" table, for lack of a better term, of the initial CTE select. CTE's are great for non-changing datasets, it is selected into memory once and then the "in-memory table" can be referenced many times in the following query(s).

Comment: @gmiley - Nope you are very wrong. Occasionally it can be spooled but this is very much an exception. In the vast majority of cases it isn't. It is a logical table expression as Stu correctly phrases it. Simple demo that it isn't a snapshot is `WITH CTE AS (SELECT NEWID() AS N)SELECT * FROM CTE C1 JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.N = C2.N`

Comment: @gmiley I concur with martin as per the comment I added above, using a CTE, view etc does not mean it is materialised "as  written", the SQL Server optimizer, being a smart-arse bit of kit, does not do that unless you go out of your way with a row-goal or additional hints or temp-table etc

Comment: @MartinSmith I don't know if you are intentionally being pedantic over the term "Table", but the initialism "CTE" stands for "Common Table Expression". If you insist, we can rename it to "Common Result Set Expression".

Comment: @gmiley - In other databases CTEs may behave as you state but in SQL Server they don't. And not sure what point you are trying to make with the last comment as it doesn't change anything. e.g. See that the underlying object behind `syslanguages` is accessed twice not once https://dbfiddle.uk/GxQz7JDK - or just try your own queries and look at the execution plans